# HardhatError: HH700: Artifact for contract "Greeter" not found

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, installation

Following the instructions on Hardhat (https://hardhat.org/getting-started#installation) to deploy a smart contract on VScode.

Previously created a Hardhat project where I changed the name from **Greeter.sol** to **Transctions.sol**

I thought this may be the problem and erased the Hardhat project. Installed another Hardhat Project but got the *same* error.

Tried running: npx hardhat clean

Error message continued:

1. Should return the new greeting once it's changed

0 passing (2s)
1 failing

My `hardhat.config.js`

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");

task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.4",
};
```

My `Greeter.sol`

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Greeter {
    string private greeting;

    constructor(string memory _greeting) {
        console.log("Deploying a Greeter with greeting:", _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }

    function setGreeting(string memory _greeting) public {
        console.log("Changing greeting from '%s' to '%s'", greeting, _greeting);
        greeting = _greeting;
    }
}
```

My `sample-test.js`

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Greeter", function () {
  it("Should return the new greeting once it's changed", async function () {
    const Greeter = await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
    const greeter = await Greeter.deploy("Hello, world!");
    await greeter.deployed();

    expect(await greeter.greet()).to.equal("Hello, world!");

    const setGreetingTx = await greeter.setGreeting("Hola, mundo!");

    // wait until the transaction is mined
    await setGreetingTx.wait();

    expect(await greeter.greet()).to.equal("Hola, mundo!");
  });
});
```

Comment: I changed the three files with what you have here and renamed Greeter.sol and didn't get errors. I can get errors like that if I change the contract name (inside the file). Sounds like a spooky issue. Perhaps delete the whole directory and start afresh?

Comment: Shameless plug: take a look at my [Hardhat-based Solidity template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template). It might automatically solve the issue that you're encountering here.